# run php script on http request without using mod_rewrite and even for robots

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is a simple problem but I expect has a very difficult solution.

I want to have a page run some PHP code on http request, without using mod_rewrite and without using javascript.

ex.
http://website.com/some_audio.mp3
when user or robot requests this link, a php script is called to process and then deny or allow the request.

I cannot use mod_rewrite for this, I know it sounds crazy just take my word for it. Also cannot use javascript either since robots would bypass this. need some kind of htaccess solution.

Comment: I'm not sure how well this would work, but you could tell apache to interpret the file as php and then `auto_prepend_file` should work.

Comment: You could use an apache AddHandler setting to set the .mp3 extension to run as a php script to do this - but even if they allow you to set your own MIME types this is messy. You should explain your situation better to help understand what kind of options we have to work with

Comment: yes, I realize my limitations are serious but this is what I have to work with. thnx

Comment: Explosion Pills may have answered this. will try it

Comment: tried to use the Addhandler directive but the mp3 file is being parsed as php and gives errors like Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=23) state=0 in must have found a <? characters in the mp3. any way to bypass this and just passthru the mp3 file while keeping it as php?

Answer (score 0):

Telling to Apache "to interpret the file as PHP" (`AddType application/x-httpd-php .mp3`) is almost the same thing as rewriting the URL so, this is not possible without using mod_rewrite or, to simplify, without making the file a PHP script. However you may type some rewrite-conditions ("something like"... not tested), but you just sayd: without rewrite

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} .*Googlebot.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+\.mp3)$ - [F,L]
```